# How to cascade delete set of enums in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have the `roles` field in `User` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "uuid")
})
public class User

   ...

   @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @NotEmpty
   private Set<Roles> roles;
```

when I try to delete user with a query, the referential integrity constraint violation occurs, because user is referenced from `User_roles` table.

How to solve this in any way?

---

`DDL` for related table shows

```
create or replace table User_roles
(
    User_id bigint not null,
    roles varchar(255) null,
    constraint FKi81fp6mx433heb7dvbxqaqvpv
        foreign key (User_id) references User (id)
);
```

i.e. it doesn't contain `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause. I need it be there.

Comment: "when I try to delete user with a query" - please show your query.

Comment: it doesn't matter, since `DDL` shows foreign table doesn't contain `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause to the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in the following way:

```java
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;

@Entity
@Table(name ="User")
public class User
{
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(
      name = "User_roles",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id"),
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
         name = "user_fk",
         foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (User_id) REFERENCES User(id) ON DELETE CASCADE")
   )
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private Set<Roles> roles;
}
```

Comment: Please show stack trace. Probably you should correct table/column names. What database do you use?

Comment: I have corrected tables/columns names. Please  recheck now