# Problem with cascading remove state in ManyToMany association

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I've got problem with delete order which contains parts. I've tried `CascadeType` and fetch but in response I've got error:

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKM25VEWW7LF2YTLPXGFELPMCEI: PUBLIC.ORDER_PARTS FOREIGN KEY(PART_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PART(ID_PART) (3)"; SQL statement:
delete from part where id_part=?
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_order")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_parts",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="client_order_id", referencedColumnName="id_order")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="part_id", referencedColumnName="id_part")})
    private List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client")
    private Client client;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Part {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_part")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "part_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name = "selected", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false" )
    private boolean selected;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parts")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public Part() {
    }

    public Part(String name, Double price, boolean selected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's stated in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many):

> For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: The only solution is create new Entity e.g. OrderParts? And then use duplicate @OneToMany annotation?

Comment: You can try to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. See , as an example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65999806/6277104). In your case, you need to use `foreignKey` or `inverseForeignKey` from the `@JoinTable` depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: `@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_order")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_parts",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="client_order_id"),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "order_fk",
                    foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (client_order_id) REFERENCES Order(id_order) ON DELETE CASCADE"),
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="part_id", referencedColumnName="id_part")})`

Comment: **It doesn't work** - is not a technical description of the problem.  Please describe how it works now, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to delete order. I haven't got error but still doesn't work deleting order

Comment: Please show how you try to delete order? Do you run your code inside some transaction? Do you want that all records corresponding to the deleted order in the `order_parts` table be deleted as well?

Comment: public Order findOrderById(Long id) {
        Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(id);
        if (order.isPresent()) {
            return order.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
                                                                                                     
    @Transactional
    public void deleteOrder(Long id) {
        Order order = findOrderById(id);
        orderRepository.delete(order);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/deleteOrder/{id}")
public String deleteOrder(@PathVariable Long id) {
    orderService.deleteOrder(id);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Service

```
@Transactional
public Order findOrderById(Long id) {
    Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(id);
    if (order.isPresent()) {
        return order.get();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

@Transactional
public void deleteOrder(Long id) {
    Order order = findOrderById(id);
    orderRepository.delete(order);
}
```